# Adding an object via sqlalchemy throws KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my first python app, I have been struggling to get migrations working correctly with flask and sqlalchemy. I finally got that working but now when I run the application, I get an error when I add an object to the table that was modified with the migration code.
This is the view the exception is thrown on db.session.add(newTag)

```
    def put(self):
    json_data = request.get_json(force=True)

    foo = json_data['foo'] if 'foo' in json_data else ''
    bar = json_data['bar'] if 'bar' in json_data else ''
    baz = json_data['baz'] if 'baz' in json_data else ''
    try:
        boo = parse(json_data['boo'])
        far = parse(json_data['far'])
    except:
        return jsonify(result='Invalid date')

    faz = json_data['faz'] if 'faz' in json_data else ''

    if faz == '':
        return jsonify(result="faz is missing")

    newTag = Tags(faz, baz, foo, bar, boo, far, True)
    db.session.add(newTag)
    db.session.commit()
    return {'Success, tag' + str(newTag.id) + ' created'}
```

My model looks like this

```
class Tags(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
faz = db.Column(db.String(255))
foo = db.Column(db.Integer)
bar = db.Column(db.Integer)
baz = db.Column(db.Integer)
boo = db.Column(db.DateTime)
far = db.Column(db.DateTime)
status = db.Column(db.Boolean)

def __init__(self, faz, foo, bar, baz, boo, far, status):
    self.faz = faz
    self.foo = foo
    self.bar = bar
    self.baz = baz
    self.boo = boo
    self.far = far
    self.status = status
```

I am not sure if any further detail is needed to assist me.
I have put SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False in the config.py file that contains my SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI.

Answer (score 5):

I have exactly the same error.

This error is realy not explicit.
i look for a response in mysql log but everything is ok.

Then i use an older version of sqlalchemy.
I work with the version 2.1 and then i pass in version 1.0.
The error i got is more clear.

To put SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS at False or True change absolutely nothing to your error.

The problem hear is the connection enter your app, your db and your sqlalchemy.

hear is my archi

```
app
main.py
models.py
views
     __init__.py
     manage.py
     views.py
```

In my init.py i put all my config

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:password@172.17.0.2/mydatabaseapp'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)
```

and then i create a class in my manager.py to manipulate my database
So i have to import db in my manager.py, i do it.

My views.py just call the methods of my manager and my main.py call the function of my views.py

But the problem is i always have this error. So i change my architecture.
I create a file config.py in my app folder i just put

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

in the file. And in my main.py i put

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:password@172.17.0.2/mydatabaseapp'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db.init_app(app)
```

then if i need to call db somewhere in my app i just call it from main.py and the problem solves.

I don't understand enough flask and is architecture to explane you the problem really sorry. I hope that reponse will help you. 
I think this error comes typically when the flask's config enter ORM and your app is not ok.